# Ios : App is not asking for location permission

Tags: ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have two the keys: NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescrition in my info.plist. Still, App is not asking for location permission. I have used nativescript and webpack to build this app. I have followed this git repository in order to code the functionality: https://github.com/nickcoury/nativescript-maps-app

Comment: The application will only ask for permission when you are trying to use a function related to location.

Answer (score 2):

Start initializing `CLLocationManager` and `startUpdatingLocation`, then the app will ask for location permission.

It will not show a popup unless you invoke `CLLocationManager` methods.